# CGPDFDocument and the trailer/encrypt dictionary

Tags: ios, security, pdf, permissions, cgpdfdocument

I am trying to get access to the /Encrypt dictionary in the Trailer to check permissions on a PDF. CGPDFDocument only gives access to the Info and Root (top level) dictionaries it seems.

**CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog**
CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages
CGPDFDocumentGetPage
CGPDFDocumentGetVersion
**CGPDFDocumentGetInfo**
CGPDFDocumentGetID

Any ideas on how to get to the file permissions beyond Printing and Copying ?

CGPDFDocumentAllowsCopying
CGPDFDocumentAllowsPrinting

Comment: Perhaps there's some base knowledge I don't have, but it's not clear what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Looking for a way to read a PDF's security permissions. There are more than just allowed to print and copy ( such as "sign" etc... )

Comment: did anyone ever figure this out?